# Rust - как сделать возврат из функции в константу при передаче строки как аргумента функции?

Tags: rust

Возможно ли реализовать возврат из функции в константу при условии, что аргументом функции является строка? Я создал тестовую функцию, при ее выполнении получаю ошибку, что значение аргумента в функции не константно.

```
const fn cf(msg: &str) -> i32 { 
  let check = msg.to_string(); 
  if check == "asd" {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test = "asd".to_string();
    const B: i32 = cf(test);
    println!("{}", B);
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, ваш код не компилируется не только и не столько из-за констант, сколько из-за того, что вы смешали в кучу два разных строковых типа и из-за [неправильного сравнения строк](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886160). Во-вторых, касательно констант вы пытаетесь получить const переменную из не-const переменной, а это невозможно. В-третих, тип `String` выполняет аллокацию памяти в куче и оттого не может быть константой. В-четвёртых, а какую задачу вы вообще решаете-то? Зачем вам понадобились константы в таком виде?

Comment: Константа нужна для дальнейшего создания массива - его размера. A fixed-size array, denoted [T; N], for the element type, T, and the non-negative compile-time constant size, N. С строковыми типами возможно да, напутал так как еще не до конца с ними разобрался в Rust.

Comment: Как-то всё равно не очень понятно. Размер массива вычисляется во время компиляции, константа вычисляется во время компиляции и значит её значение заранее известно — тогда что вам мешает просто сразу объявить массив нужного размера без всех этих манипуляций с константами, функциями и строками?

Comment: Смысл в том, что по имени файла (строка - аргумент в функции) возвращается результат в виде константы (число), которое используется для создания массива. В зависимости от имени файла значение размера массива может быть или 7 или 9. Мне в константу не строка нужна, а число. Строка используется в функции только в условии для возврат значения из функции.

Comment: Логика та же самая — если имена файлов это заранее известные константы, значит вы заранее знаете, где в каком массиве нужно использовать или 7 или 9, тогда почему бы просто не объявить эти массивы размерами 7 или 9 вручную без всех этих манипуляций с константами, функциями и строками?

Comment: Массив один и он формируется один раз. Это не два разных массива. В зависимости от выбранного файла формируется разный размер массива. Имя файла получается заранее не известно. Оно становится известно только когда его указывают в командной строке как ключ.

Comment: Хотя я понял вашу мысль, заранее сформировать просто два массива с указанием размера.

Comment: Значит вы хотите невозможного. Нельзя создать константу из значения, которое не является константной. Значение константы должно быть известно в момент компиляции — ключ командной строки таковым не является

Comment: Если вам принципиально расположить массив в стеке, то можно сделать один массив длиной 9 и в зависимости от ключа создавать мутабельный срез на него длиной 7 или 9 (это будет экономнее по памяти, чем два отдельных массива, и возможно упростит код). Если не принципиально, то использовать `Vec` будет в миллион раз проще чем возиться с массивами

Comment: Хорошая идея со срезом, спасибо.

Comment: Еще доп вопрос, а в Rust можно через условие if формировать константы или также исходя из логики, что она не может быть заранее определена или вообще не определена он не даст скомпилироваться?

Comment: Использовать if и match в const-функциях можно с версии 1.46, однако из-за того, что значения констант вычисляются в момент компиляции, const-функции сильно ограничены и делать в них можно далеко не всё (пока я писал первые комментарии, я параллельно пытался сделать сравнение строковых констант, но как-то не преуспел). Если вы попытаетесь запихнуть не-const выражение (например, ключ командной строки) в const-переменную, то код просто не скомпилируется